# Calculate width in scss

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

I have a little question, I don't understand what does it mean in css file

```
(100% - 60px) / 2) = ?????
```

Thanks for help

Comment: This is just a math equation. 100% of the width minus 60px then divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
(100% - 60px) / 2) = ?????
```

in CSS the syntax to this expression will be :

```
calc(calc(100% - 60px)/2);
```

which means :

let's suppose we are talking about a property such as width, then for the current element in which we are writing this CSS, its width will be equal to px value of(100% of parent width) minus 60 px and its output divide by 2, then the result will be converted back to `%` and that will be the %value of width of Current element.

and the other way :

```
(100% parent width) = X px;
X px - 60 px = Y px;
(Y px converted to %) = Z %;
z % / 2 = result in %;
```